# asp.net In gridview, if datafield is an array, how can show it?

Tags: gridview

```
grid.DataSource = list; //list is a Question[], each Question contains a QuestionText and Choices[]
grid.DataBind();
```

How can i show them like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Au7.png

What should i code in asp code?

```
<asp:GridView ID="OptionsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="//here,what should i code?" HeaderText="Options" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For customized output like this, you will want to make use of `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%-- you can use custom tags here and
             Eval("Property") to get values from the
             data source, or ((Question)Container.DataItem).Property
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

For your second column, you will need a second display control that can show multiple data output, such as a `ListView`, or `Repeater`.  For example, how you might show an unordered list of choices in the second column (this would be in another `asp:TemplateField`):

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater DataSource='<%#((Question)Container.DataItem).Choices#>' ...
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%#Eval("ChoiceText")#></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually, i am new to asp.net. Do you mean that:1.create a TemplateField which use gridview with column "Question" and use ((Question)Container.DataItem).QuestionText to show the questions. 2. Then create another TemplateField inside above one, use repeater with column "Choices" and use ((Question)Container.DataItem).Choices to show choices.If yes, what is the "ChoiceText" mean?